# Nexted resource routes with :only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Essentially I'm trying to combine the two resource declarations into one command.
     resource :documents, only: [:create, :destroy] 
     resource :documents do
        collection :sort
     end

I tried mixing the two together, I don't want all the extra methods rails gives you by default.
Obviously

```
resource :documents, only: [:create, :destroy] do
  collection :sort
end
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
collection :sort
```

try something like:

```
get 'sort' => 'some#action', on: :collection
```

Comment: @YuriBarbashov. It worth it. If the author decides to change the path for the `documents` resources, it'll simply specify: `resources :documents, path: 'docs'`. With your approach he'll also need to change documents to docs once more, in `get 'documents/sort'`. This isn't Rails way!